# How to push hive data to Google sheets

Tags: database, flutter, google-sheets, hive

I want to know about how to push data to google spread sheets from device hive data

nothing

nothing nothing

Comment: Please check out (SOF Help Center)[https://stackoverflow.com/help] to learn more about how to write a good question so we can help you with the problems you are facing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.